# Silverlight chart toolkit 5: Bar series data binding

Tags: silverlight

We are developing silverlight application. We have to develop bind bar chart series with RIA Domain data source control.

Code snippet as below.

```
<chartingToolKit:Chart Title="My bar chart">
  <chartingToolKit:BarSeries Title="Actual" 
                             ItemsSource="{Binding
                             ElementName=actualVsTargetEnergySPDataDomainDataSource,Path=Data}"
                             IndependentValueBinding="{Binding ActualEnergyConsumption}"
                             DependentValueBinding="{Binding XaxisData}">
    <chartingToolKit:BarSeries.IndependentAxis>
      <chartingToolKit:CategoryAxis Orientation="Y"
                                    ShowGridLines="True"
                                    Title="Actual"/>
    </chartingToolKit:BarSeries.IndependentAxis>
    <chartingToolKit:BarSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
      <chartingToolKit:LinearAxis Orientation="X"
                                  ShowGridLines="True"
                                  Title="Target"/> 
    </chartingToolKit:BarSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
  </chartingToolKit:BarSeries>
</chartingToolKit:Chart>
```

However, it is not showing any data.
Instead of domain data source binding, if we provide static data then it shows values.

Can you please let me know, how to bind values to bar series?